# Hive Dynamic Partition table issue with altering partition

Tags: hive, alter-table, database-partitioning

I Have table with dynamic partition  "campaign" and static partitions year and month(that means I am giving there value while inserting/creating partitions).

'ABC' Partition by (year='2011', month='08', campaign)

As dynamic partition is only supported when its followed by static partitions namesly year and month. But my use case is opposite

I want something like this -->
  'ABC' Partition by (campaign, year='2011', month='08')

So that i can see for campaigns results per year and month.

By any chance, OR any other option by which I can do that? something like this??

ALTER TABLE ABC PARTITION (y='2011', m='08',campaign) RENAME/ALTER PARTITIONs (campaign,y='2011', m='08');

Answer (score 2):

A partition isn't defined as static or dynamic in the metastore; Just INSERT/LOAD queries define partitions as static or dynamic. You can run an insertion that uses all-dynamic partitions by using `SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=nonstrict`.

See: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial

Answer (score 1):

if you set your partition to `strict` mode you can perform it

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=strict
```

BUT IF you set to nonstrict mode and perform dynamically then

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=nonstrict
```

We cannot perform `ALTER` on the Dynamic partition.